# Symbols from `fourier-orns` not working

Tags: fonts, symbols, fourier

I'm trying to use `fourier-orns` in a LaTeX document. If I include `\usepackage{fourier-orns}` but do not try to use any of the symbols from the package, my document compiles without issues. I'm using TeXworks on a Windows machine.

If I try to include any of the symbols, the document fails to compile:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\begin{document}
Hello, world \starredbullet
\end{document}
```

This is what I get from the log generated:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.12) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.12.21)  11 JAN 2021 16:17
entering extended mode
**"./hello world.tex"
("hello world.tex"
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count177
\c@section=\count178
\c@subsection=\count179
\c@subsubsection=\count180
\c@paragraph=\count181
\c@subparagraph=\count182
\c@figure=\count183
\c@table=\count184
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fourier\fourier-orns.sty"
Package: fourier-orns 2020/03/03 2.2 fourier-ornaments package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def"
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count185
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
)
No file "hello world".aux.
\openout1 = `"hello world.aux"'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+futs on input line 7.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fourier\ufuts.fd"
File: ufuts.fd 2004/03/02 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for U/futs.
) [1

{C:/Users/dbmag/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] ("hello world.a
ux") ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 529 strings out of 479697
 8820 string characters out of 2877008
 272088 words of memory out of 3000000
 17692 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 403763 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 51i,4n,59p,145b,100s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

!pdfTeX error: miktex-pdftex.exe (file fourier-orns): Font fourier-orns at 552 
not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: It happens from time to time that type1 fonts are not added to the postscript fonts database. Try running `MiKTeX Settings` and click on the `Tasks > Refresh font map files` menu item.

Comment: @Bernard I refreshed the font map files and it didn't work, but then checked for/installed package updates and closed and reopened MiKTeX and it did work – my suspicious is that the successful part was refreshing font map files combined with restarting MiKTeX. If you convert your comment into an answer I can mark it as accepted; thank you!

Comment: Fine! I don't think  it will be necessary to post the comment as an answer, there are already similar answers, but I don't know where, exactly  (including from me…)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error. The `MikTeX > Tasks > Refresh font map files` and restarting MikTeX didn't work for me.

Then, I tried `MikTeX > updates > checked for updates > update now`, which works for me.